# PHP / MySQL Query within a query

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello I have a table which has a list of school courses. (schoolcourses)
The table gets inner joined with another table of instructors that are assigned to that course (instructors).

So far easy.

The complex part is within the same query I need to get the status of the instructor. There is another table called course_acceptance_history. So when an instructor is assigned a course he accepts the course. And it inserts a record into course_acceptance_history.

An insturctor CAN accept, then deny a course, then another instructor can ACCEPT the same course.  So in other words course_acceptance_history can have 10 entries for the same course.

How do i pick the MOST RECENT record for a course from course_acceptance_history during the query that gets all the courses?

This is what my query looks like but i think i need a sub  query to pull only the record from course_acceptance_history with the highest ID for that course and instructor ID

Example

```
    SELECT * FROM schoolcourses

INNER JOIN instructors ON schoolcourses.courseinstructor = instructors.instructorsid
INNER JOIN course_acceptance_history ON schoolcourses.schoolcoursesid = course_acceptance_history.courseid
```

I guess I need to merge the query above with

```
SELECT * FROM course_acceptance_history WHERE instructorid=$insid AND courseID=$courseID ORDERBY ID DESC
```

Comment: Are the acceptances time stamped or indexed somehow to indicate order of entry?

Comment: I would just add the most_recent field to the course_acceptance_history :)
When adding new acceptance, first set most_recent=0 for this instructor and course, than add new entry with most_recent=1

Comment: I hope you're absolutely certain your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because putting `$_POST` data directly into the query creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM schoolcourses
    INNER JOIN instructors ON
        schoolcourses.courseinstructor = instructors.instructorsid
    INNER JOIN course_acceptance_history ON
        schoolcourses.schoolcoursesid = course_acceptance_history.courseid
WHERE course_acceptance_history.id =
    (SELECT id
        FROM course_acceptance_history
        WHERE instructorid=instructors.id
        AND courseID=schoolcourses.schoolcoursesid
        ORDER BY ID DESC
        LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your column names so you may need to edit to suit, but you get the general idea I hope.

Comment: Thank you deatbabel. I do have a question though. I am trying to pull a list of ALL scheduled courses that are in the future and show the acceptance status (most recent). So where would I throw that in  WHERE coursedate > curdate

Comment: at the end of the query above, add an AND and then your additional where clause.  e.g. SELECT * FROM x WHERE a=1 AND b=2

Comment: So TWO WHERE statements? Before the subquery there is a WHERE statement.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No, one WHERE statement with an AND in it.